SQL Server command working from the command line but not from a stored procedure
I have a problem trying to compile a stored procedure from within a stored procedure. I create a very simple script file (D:\tmp\test_proc.sql) with compilable code to demonstrate the issue:
CREATE PROCEDURE new_rtn
AS
BEGIN
 PRINT 'Hi!';
END

Next I try to compile this file using the following procedure:
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_compile
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE
    @fn              NVARCHAR(35)   = 'sp_compile'
   ,@cmd             NVARCHAR(500)
   ,@db              NVARCHAR(60)  = DB_NAME()
   ,@server          NVARCHAR(90)  = @@SERVERNAME
   ,@script_file     NVARCHAR(500) = 'D:\\tmp\\test_proc.sql'
   ,@error_file      NVARCHAR(500) = 'D:\\tmp\\errors.txt'
   ,@q_tst_rtn_nm    NVARCHAR(60)  = 'sp_new_rtn'
   ,@ret             INT = NULL

   PRINT '000: starting';

   -- Test setup
   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_new_rtn;

   -- CREATE the DOS cmd
   SET @cmd = 
      CONCAT
      (
            'SQLCMD.EXE'
         ,' -S ',@server
         ,' -E -d ',@db
         ,' -i ',@script_file
         ,' -o ',@error_file
      );

   -- Print the DOS testable version - remove the escape \ and change the error file for comparison
   PRINT CONCAT('060: @cmd=
',REPLACE(REPLACE(@cmd,'errors.txt','errors2.txt'),'\\','\'));
   -- Run the DOS cmd to create the procedure

   EXEC @ret = master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
   SET @cmd = 'echo %ERRORLEVEL% > D:\tmp\out.txt'; -- dump output to out.txt
   EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;

   -- Check the postconditions
   PRINT '065: checking postconditions...';

   -- POST 01: rtn exists in db or EX 63200, 'failed to create the procedure'
   IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = 'new_rtn')
   BEGIN
      PRINT ' ERROR: 071:  [new_rtn] does not exist';
      -- list the error line
      SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\tmp\errors.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) F;
      THROW 63200, 'failed to create procedure', 1;
   END

   -- Processing complete
   PRINT '800: Processing complete';
END
GO
/*
EXEC sp_compile;
*/

This fails with the error:

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : The client cannot connect to the server because the requested instance was not available. Use SQL Server Configuration Manager to make sure the SQL Server instance is configured correctly. .

BUT if I run the command directly from dos
SQLCMD.EXE -S DEVI9\SQLEXPRESS -E -d Tg -i D:\tmp\test_proc.sql -o D:\tmp\errors2.txt  it works.
My server is DevI9\SQLEXPRESS.
To help with reproducing the error the compile routine prints the dos equivalent command line replacing the \ with \ and writing to a different error file for comparison.
I am using Windows 10.0.19045 and

Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-GDR) (KB5035432) - 16.0.1115.1 (X64)   Mar 15 2024 01:13:46   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0  (Build 19045: ) (Hypervisor).

I guess there must be some configuration I need to sort out - any ideas?
Thanks.
Summary and extra things I tried:
So the strategy I am using is to create the routine to be compiled in a script file and compile that from a stored procedure using xp_cmdshell.
This fails because of access issues however when I run the command from a dos box it works fine.
this has to be a permissions thing I guess. I am an admin on my machine but am not running SSMS as admin ... but when I do run SSMS as admin I still get the same issue:

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : The client cannot connect to the server because the requested instance was not available. Use SQL Server Configuration Manager to make sure the SQL Server instance is configured correctly.


" trying to compile a stored prodedure from within a stored procdure" - You shouldn't normally ever need to do thisd - so why are you wanting to do this?

What tool are you using to define and run that procedure (other than sqlcmd.exe)? Are you using SSMS? LinqPad? Dbeaver?

when I run the command from a dos box it works fine I doubt it. Modern SQL Server drivers are not available for MS-DOS. Use correct names for the tools that you use.

Maybe something weird is going on with slashes. I also don't know what you're doing to be honest. Maybe we don't wanna know?

Also can't really guess why you are doing this but why are you trying to do this in TSQL specifically? Rather than from some other environment better suited to the task where  you don't have to do things like enable xp_cmdshell?

I just tried your script and it works just fine here on sql server 2022, so the issue is probably to do with your server setup

This procedure has so many issues: calling a procedure anything starting sp_ is reserved for Microsoft, you're very lucky it doesn't clash with an exisiting system proc. The data types are all the wrong sizes, and there is  no escaping in the command. Calling out to xp_cmdshell seems ridiculous, you may as well run this from a normal command prompt yourself. There is absolutely no need to do this from T-SQL in the first place.

Right, first thanks for all responses.

In response to Dai, this is part of a much bigger project in which I have set of routines that auto generated a pair of test routines for any so or function. Using tSQLt. They interrogate the tested routines metadata and provide a framework in which all I have to do is add lines of test data in the main routine which calls the helper with inputs and expected outputs. Finally I can easily do tdd. Which is vital once the projects pass about 500 routines.

This last bit checks all routines in the dbo schema an if there is not at least one test it generates a line of sql that will generate the 2 test routines for it.

Yes Dai I am using SSMS for this. I used C# before with both ef and Dapper. Frankly there are issues whichever way I do it. I am tired of Microsoft's instant wonders. Yes SQL is slow to develop, and SQL server often faults with things like pipe broken when running some things in process. But SQL server has pretty good meta data APIs.

In response to Charlie, no reason not to prefix with sp_. I am not daft, of course I check for lashes... And as for data type sizes this is a minimal cut down piece of code to demonstrate the error. What do think is wrong with the data sizes?

Charlie if you know of a better way to compile a 4000 character plus stored procedure from SQL code please tell me.

Charlie there is no escaping in the SQL command call BECAUSE IT WONT WORK IF YOU DO!

I'd have thought you'd need to run EXECUTE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/execute-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16
